# Definition of fragility

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology, definition

What does it mean for a solution to a system of differential equations to be ***fragile***?

A context for the term can be found here:
[image]

This is taken from [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=H40qXJ7wY1IC&pg=PA332&lpg=PA332&dq=fragility+of+arenstorf&source=bl&ots=4SbeYlzGF0&sig=T_i34SAlwjkvdqUfAnrRuTQig7s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xWt8T8fbGaGf0QWSxLCgDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=fragility%20of%20arenstorf&f=false) in *Mathematical Methods for Mechanics: A Handbook With MATLAB Experiments* by Eckart Gekeler.

Does it mean it is small perturbations grow over time?

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Thanks for adding the page!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: What is $\mu$? $ $

Comment: @draks: It is just a measure of mass.